# Reactivity of boron nitride BN, reaction with Cl2

Tags: boron-family

lately I've been interested in chemistry of boron and it's properties.. and I am looking for more information. For example I can't really seem to find lot of information about boron nitride BN other than its possible structures. I know that BN is relatively unreactive, and some stated reations found are with F$_2$ or HF, but are described reations with other halogens? With Cl$_2$? I would appreciate even literature recomandations, to find out more.

Thank you, for your time.

Comment: (Some time ago we decided against using $ in titles.) Now to the point. Never heard of such. At high temperature, maybe. Then again, if a compound is so unreactive that somebody bothers to react it with fluorine... well, that's a telling detail.

Comment: Cubic or hexagonal BN?

Comment: @Mithoron Hexagonal BN